# How to detect when owner form is closed from an inner control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to detect when owner form closes (from a control inside it)?

UPD I need the control to know that it's form is closing, *not vice versa*

Comment: Did you check the Closing event on the form?

Comment: add event to child form and rise it when parent form closing

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Do you want a) the form to know that it is being closed due to some action taken inside a control, or b) the control to know that the form is closing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Credits to Fredrik Mörk for this solution:

```
FindForm().FormClosing += parentForm_FormClosing;
```

Comment: You can use the [Control.FindForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform.aspx) method instead of looping.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk - wow, I didn't know about this method, updated the answer. I will delete my answer if you create yours. It would be fair I think.

Comment: That method is not so easy to find, since it quite badly named (in my opinion, at least). Regarding the answer, just let it stay. It's a community effort, right? :-)

Comment: _When_ I can call this method safely (be sure it's not null)?

Comment: When you are sure that control is already added to the form. You could use ParentChanged for this.

Comment: @Alex Aza -- This won't work if the control is _first_ added to a parent control (e.g. a Panel control), and _that_ control is added to the form. Then the first control's ParentChanged event will _not_ fire.

Answer (score 3):

You should intercept **FormClosing** event. In FormClosingEventArgs the variable CloseReason will show you why is the form closing. Your best bet is intercepting when this variable equals **UserClosing** enumerated value.

Comment: There is no FormClosing _inside the control_

Comment: @user626528: no, but the control can still attach an event handler to the `FormClosing` event of the parent form.

Comment: With the new update from OP i think Fredrik Mörk & Alex Aza answer is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

The form owner closing is when a form is closed by another parent form that can close the form or the form is closed when the parent form is closed.

Use the form closing event to check if another form closed the form:

```
private void AppMainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing)
    {
       // do something
    }
    else
    {
       // do nothing
    }
}
```